# Why am I getting 401 Unauthorized when I query my Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have a Angular application and a separate Web API solution built with .NET Core. I have successfully setup authentication with Azure AD B2C. I am able to login to the angular application. I have configured my client application and azure to secure the following resource: http://localhost/api/Profile/GetProfile.

When I navigate to the profile route in my application I am receiving a id_token and a access_token. I get 401 not authorized when trying to make my api call from my ClientApp. However, I am able to open that url successfully in a new tab (outside of my application). I am trying to achieve the opposite of this. i.e. it should 401 from a browser when not logged in but 200 from my ClientApp. What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I'm putting in my Startup.cs:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C");
```

Then later down I have:

```
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
```

I added the following to my controller:

```
        [Authorize]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding authorization as well.

1. In  `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method

```
services.AddAuthorization();
// You can pass option if requires, for example
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Role", "Admin"));
});

In that case, in controller use
[Authorize(Policy="Admin")]
```

2. In `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)` method as well.

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
```